# Unreachable code when calling an inherited assembly function in Solidity

Tags: solidity

Compiling the code

```
contract Bar {

    function blockingFunction() public pure returns (bool) {
        assembly {
            return(0,0x20)
        }
    }
}

contract Foo is Bar {

    function foo() public pure returns(bool) {
        bool result = blockingFunction();
        uint256 i = 0;
        if (i == 0) return result;
        else return !result;
    }
}
```

gives me a warning

```
Warning: Unreachable code.
  --> contracts/implementation/Neki.sol:18:9:
   |
18 |         uint256 i = 0;
   |         ^ (Relevant source part starts here and spans across multiple lines).
```

which makes no sense to me. The `blockingFunction` call seems to block the following code execution, even though it should return a boolean. Can someone tell me how to fix this? This is my `hardhat.config.ts`

```typescript
import { HardhatUserConfig } from "hardhat/config";
import "@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox";

const config: HardhatUserConfig = {
  solidity: "0.8.9",
  mocha: {
    timeout: 100000000
  }
}

export default config;
```

Answer (score 0):

A fix was calling the inherited method through `this` as `this.blockingFunction()`.